# Conditional Formatting very slow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, javascript, client-object-model

i am using SharePoint 2010. I built a webpart which is displaying elements from another list on the same page.
This works fine and fast but when i put in the conditional formatting the loading process of the site tooks a very long time, around 30-80 seconds.
The aim is to view these elements (there are three: red, yellow and green) like a kind of a traffic light.

[Code in SharePoint Workspace](http://pastebin.com/ZU10fjTk)

Any tips for improving the performance?

Comment: usually I prefer use JavaScript instead of XSLT for many reason: is faster and you use the client process to formatting the result

Comment: I never used JavaScript before but I'll give it a try ;)

Comment: ok seems it works a little  bit but now i have the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086047/accessing-sharepoint-list-with-javascript-variable-storage

Comment: Ok I'm going to ask you here and in the other question too... it's an hard work :)
Please remember to vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above I prefer to use JavaScript for a couple of reason:

- the workload is distributed on the clients instead of the server and that should give you better performance
- it is more easy to integrate on your HTML